# Google analytics tracking id not displaying

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

i setup "Google Analytics" from Firebase. I am using "FirebaseAnalytics" in my android application but i want to also integrate google analytics but when i opened google https://analytics.google.com/ and go to Admin section i can't find "Tracking Id"

> Screen Shot Of Google Analytics Admin Section :
>   [image]
>   i viewed all sections but tracking id not displayed in any section.

Comment: There's a walk through here on how to integrate the two https://www.kristaseiden.com/step-by-step-setting-up-an-app-web-property/

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics UI upgraded I guess. To get tracking info I follow the below steps.

1. Go to Admin.
2. Click create a property in the second column.
3. Enter property setup and click show advanced options.
4. Enable Create a Universal Analytics property by the right-side button.
5. Enter your website address
6. Check second check box - Create a Universal Analytics property only
7. Enter business information and create the property.
8. you can find your tracking id.

Answer (score 0):

**Find your Measurement ID**

- Sign in to Analytics.
- Click Admin.
- In the Property column, use the menu to select the property you want, then click Data Streams > Web.

The Measurement ID is displayed at the top right.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9310895?hl=en

Comment: What if there is no "data streams" option in the property column? How TF is there wrong instructions? I dont get it.

Comment: Probably it isn't a GA4 Property but an Universal Analytics Property.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a property there is a link/button **Show advanced options**. Click it and toggle Create a Universal Analytics property.

Enabling this will make the Tracking info show on your property. See attached image

[image]